# Post value of select always -1 / Can't get previously selected value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select_val = $('#myselect').val();
  console.log(select_val)

  if (select_val > 0) {
    $('.test').show()
  } else {
    $('.test').hide()
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <form action="submit.php;" class="form-horizontal" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <select name="myselect" id="myselect" class="form-control">
      <option value="-1">Select</option>
      <option value="1">TEST1</option>
      <option value="2">TEST2</option>
      <option value="3">TEST3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="send">
  </form>

  <div class='test'>
    Value is more than 0
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check snippet above. Here is what I'm trying to do:

1. When user click submit, he is directed to submit.php
2. If they go back to previous page (form page) some element will be shown telling them which value they selected. (In this case I just show "Value is more than 0")

You can see in the snippet that when you submit and go back it is correctly showing that value is above 0. However in my website, I can't replicate this even though use almost the exact same code.

It seems the div element with the class test is loaded when #myselect is still -1. I understand that this would happen if the code was loading before the DOM was ready, however I made sure to use `$(document).ready(function()`

This is code used on production site. On load, the value of projectid can be less than 9 and #notification will still never be shown. But if value of projectid changes, it will be shown accordingly. What could I be doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var projectid = $('#projectid').val();
    if(projectid <= 9 && projectid > 0){
        $('#notification').show();
    }else{
        $('#notification').hide();
    }

    $('#projectid').change(function(e) {
        var projectid = $(e.target).val();
        if(projectid <= 9 && projectid > 0){
          $('#notification').show();
        }else{
          $('#notification').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Since your example snippet doesn't match the code you are having problems with, its really anyone's guess ;) In your actual code: Are you sure the element has the right `id="projectid"`? Are you sure php is echoing out the `selected="selected"` of the correct `option` element? Have you looked at the output in the browser devtools to make sure of these things?

Comment: Yes I did check all of these things multiple times. As I said the code is pretty much the same. Except for behavior in select value. On load, #projectid value is -1, then is set to the user set value

Comment: Regarding "pretty much the same"; They must not be or you would not be having this problem. What you have shown here is guesswork because you are not providing the actual initial html output from php where this javascript is in regards too. You keep saying "#projectid" has a value, how is that determined? Its a `select`, which means it has multiple `option`, each with a `value`. Unless one is specifically set as `selected`, then what you get could be different based on browser default behaviors.